# Iterate over a reference to Chars

Tags: rust

I have a function that receives a reference to `Chars`:

```rust
use std::str::Chars;

fn main() {
    let s = "aoeuaoeu".to_string();
    my_func(&s.chars())
}

fn my_func(chars: &Chars) {
    for x in chars {
        dbg!(x);
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile, because `chars` on line 9 is the reference rather than the iterator:

```
error[E0277]: `&std::str::Chars<'_>` is not an iterator
 --> src/main.rs:9:14
  |
9 |     for x in chars {
  |              ^^^^^ `&std::str::Chars<'_>` is not an iterator
  |
  = help: the trait `std::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for `&std::str::Chars<'_>`
  = note: required by `std::iter::IntoIterator::into_iter`
```

I've tried whack-a-mole with `&` and `*` etc, to no avail. Is there any way of iterating over it without an additional allocation?

I'm not in control of the calling function, so the function does need to take a reference (i.e. can't change the caller to `my_func(s.chars()`.

Comment: To iterate, you **must** modify the iterator. You have to clone it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you hold a immutable reference to `Chars` you are not free to mutate it and `Iterator` is only auto implemented for mutable reference [`impl<I: Iterator + ?Sized> Iterator for &mut I`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/traits/iterator.rs.html#2605). For the very good reason then [`next()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next) require `&mut self`.

You have many solutions: take it as mutable reference, clone it or take it by value:

```rust
use std::str::Chars;

fn main() {
    let s = "aoeuaoeu".to_string();
    my_func(&mut s.chars())
}

fn my_func(chars: &mut Chars) {
    for x in chars {
        dbg!(x);
    }
}
```

```rust
use std::str::Chars;

fn main() {
    let s = "aoeuaoeu".to_string();
    my_func(&s.chars())
}

fn my_func(chars: &Chars) {
    for x in chars.clone() {
        dbg!(x);
    }
}
```

```rust
use std::str::Chars;

fn main() {
    let s = "aoeuaoeu".to_string();
    my_func(s.chars())
}

fn my_func(chars: Chars) {
    for x in chars {
        dbg!(x);
    }
}
```

Take by value is probably what the want.

Comment: Great! But then why the error message `&std::str::Chars<'_> is not an iterator`? Why doesn't it say something like "Requires mutation and holds immutable reference"?

Comment: @Maximilian That could be an improvement for the future, but that not easy to detect this kind of situation.

Comment: Thanks @stargateur. I'm more asking what that means; totally understand that it can be difficult to detect. i.e. is it that `&mut std::str::Chars<'_>` is an iterator? Or that `&mut Chars` dereferences to the iterator?

Comment: Ah great @Stargatour, I see your response more clearly now, thanks for the link to the `Impl`